# I am trying to create a start and stop button with a keyboard press

Tags: python, pyautogui, python-keyboard

I am using the keyboard library to create a button that starts and stops with the press of a button and I keep getting errors
this is the code

```
while True:
    if keyboard.on_press('esc') == True:
        if start == 0:
            start = 1
        else:
            start = 0
    while start == 1:
        print('yes')
        sleep(1)
```

and this is the error im getting while pressing the 'p' key

```
yes
yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\olawa\PycharmProjects\dj4e\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_generic.py", line 22, in invoke_handlers
    if handler(event):
  File "C:\Users\olawa\PycharmProjects\dj4e\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 474, in <lambda>
    return hook(lambda e: e.event_type == KEY_UP or callback(e), suppress=suppress)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a function to `keyboard.on_press`

Try:

```py
def pressed(key):
    if key.name == 'esc':
        # Do something here

keyboard.on_press(pressed)

while True:
    # Do something else while you wait
```

Comment: would it be if key == ... or while key ==...

Comment: It would be `if`. Just add a while loop after this code (edited my answer with this)

Comment: i am sorry if im asking dumb questions, but i don't still understand you

Comment: What the `on_press` function does is it calls `pressed` when a key is pressed. You then only need a `while` loop to keep the code going.

Comment: The callback gets a `KeyboardEvent` that has `name`, `code` and `time` members.  You'll need `key.name == 'esc'`.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used the keyboard library much.

Comment: I've never used it either.  I just read the documentation 

Answer (score 0):

it works now thanks

```
start = 1

def pressed(key):
    global start
    if key.name == 'esc':
        if start == 0 :
            start = 1
        elif start == 1:
            start = 0

keyboard.on_press(pressed)

while start == 1:
    print('yes')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I think you need `global start` underneath `def pressed(key):`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).